# Go package naming

Tags: go, go-chi

How do I reference project packages correctly? I have the following folder structure:

```
/sbp
    /models.go
    /controllers.go
/main.go
```

In `main.go` I'd like to call my controller action from `sbp.controllers`. I can't seem to find a way to correctly reference it

**`main.go`**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    ...
    "github.com/pressly/chi"
)

var sess = session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("ap-southeast-1"),
}))
var dynamo = dynamodb.New(sess)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Get("/", GetInvestments) // How do I call sbp.controller.GetInvestments?
    r.Post("/", AddInvestment)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

**`sbp/controller.go`**

```
package sbp

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/pressly/chi/render"
)

// AddInvestment Adds an investment
func AddInvestment(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
}

// GetInvestments Gets list of investments
func GetInvestments(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
}
```

I tried importing "sbp/controller", or even "github.com/jiewmeng/finance/sbp/controller" but they seem to be auto removed my VSCode, so I think its invalid?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your editor is automatically running `goimports`, which means it will remove unused imports. So simply adding it to your `imports` section isn't good enough; you also have to *use* the import.

It looks like your proper import path would be "github.com/jiewmeng/finance/sbp".  Then you need to reference it as well:

```
package main

import (
    // other imports
    "github.com/jiewmeng/finance/bp"
)

func main() {
    // whatever
    http.Handle("/somepath", http.HandlerFunc(sbp.AddInvestment))
}
```